# Why didn't Nick Fury mention previous alien encounters?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers, captain-marvel

After watching *Captain Marvel*, I had this question why Nick Fury didn't discuss all the previous alien attacks which took place in *Captain Marvel* timeline with to the Avengers.

Why did Fury hide the secret about the Skrulls and Captain Marvel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the Skrull nor Captain Marvel nor anything related to theses event (except the Tesseract) were on earth or did pose a threat to earth.

The Avengers are group of extraordinary people to stop threats which the military can't handle on its own. Its like a company. Nick Fury is the manager and the Avengers are his team. No manager tells the team about stuff that doesn't affect the team at all and there was literally no reason to tell them about the events. They would have gained nothing from it.

So basically to answer the question: There was no need nor profit to tell the Avengers about the Skrulls and Captain Marvel!

Comment: Yeah. That makes Sence

Comment: But in Avengers 1st movie when Captain America and Iron Man find out that SHIELD plans to use the Tesseract to make weapons. He blames it on Thor telling that the incident that happened in Thor 1st movie made them realize that the are ridiculously out gunned and not alone in this world. Why din't he feel that after the Captain Marvel movie incident's itself

Comment: @Thanthu that exact same question has been discussed somewhere on SE already. Either here or sci-fi SE. I'll try to find it. [Here it is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208123/if-nick-fury-and-coulson-already-knew-about-aliens-kree-and-skrull-why-did-the)

Answer (score 3):

Although almost certainly this is a [retcon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroactive_continuity), it's actually in keeping with Nick's personality.

From conversations in The Avengers between Tony Stark, Steve Rogers and Bruce Banner, where Tony is expressing his concern that they are not being told the entire truth:

> Tony Stark: An intelligence agency that fears intelligence? Historically, not awesome.

He's referring to the fact that he and Bruce are both very intelligent, and could help analyze information to search for a solution.  Instead they are being given very specific tasks, like find the Tesseract.  Later in the same conversation:

> Tony Stark: He's a spy. Captain, he's THE spy. His secrets have secrets.

Steve Rogers gets the same treatment in Captain America: The Winter Soldier.  Steve is not told about the mission that Natasha Romanoff has when they go to rescue hostages from the ship:

> Nick Fury: It's called compartmentalization. Nobody spills the secrets, because nobody knows them all.
>
> Steve Rogers: Except you.
>
> Nick Fury: You're wrong about me. I do share. I'm nice like that.

Nick also doesn't trust anyone except Maria Hill to keep the secret that actually he survived the attack on him, until it is clear that Steve and Natasha are going to be killed by Hydra.

All this is to just show that it's in keeping with Nick's approach to have a 'need to know' attitude.

As other's have said, the theft of the Tesseract was the issue at hand.  They know Loki was responsible and his last outing in New Mexico was about as much information as Nick felt he needed to share about threats from the past.